# How to let other apps take over microphone access?

Tags: android, microphone, audiorecord

Is there any way to know when another app is trying to access the microphone so i can let the other app use it?
My current app keeps recording in the background but it blocks other apps access to the microphone, is there a way to let other apps take over microphone access?

Comment: FYI, you won't able to access microphone in the background since Android P.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder! I have already informed the development team about that, and when the time comes the app will only be recording in the foreground for android P and up devices, but for android versions below P is there any way to yield microphone access?

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your use case. Theoretically you cannot "borrow" the permission from other apps for security reasons but nothing would prevent the app that already holds the permission to expose recording as "service". I do not mean Android Service here, but rather ability of letting other apps to ask your app (i.e. via special `Intent` or any other way) to do the recording  and then return recorded data back.

And as already mentioned, keep in mind, this won't work on Android P as no longer available when app is not in foreground.

And we talk about non-rooted devices, because on rooted, you may do not care the permissions that much.

Comment: Hmm... I don't really need two apps to be recording at the same time, i just need to stop recording whenever another app needs the microphone, is there any callback or listener or broadcast to allow that, or is there any workaround?  The problem is i don't really know how to detect when another app needs the microphone, and also when to release the microphone.